# properties of eigenvalues/eigenvectors of a special matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

The $N \times N$ matrix I am facing has the following form:

\begin{bmatrix}
 1 &2  & 3 & 4 & 5 & \cdots\\
 2 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & \cdots\\
  3 & 3 & 3 & 4  & 5 & \cdots\\
 4 & 4 & 4 & 4 & 5 & \cdots\\
 5 & 5 & 5 & 5 & 5 & \cdots \\
  \cdots& \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots &\cdots
\end{bmatrix}

Currently the only thing I knew was the determinant of the matrix is $(-1)^{N+1}N$.

I am not sure whether there exists some certain analytic form of the eigenvalues, but any properties of the eigenvalues or eigenvectors will be helpful. Thanks!

Comment: To begin with, this is a symmeteric matrix. So maybe you should look for eigen value properties of symmetric matrixs

Comment: Thanks! But symmetry only implies it has real eigenvalues...

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's any "analytic form" for the eigenvalues other than that they are roots of the characteristic polynomial, which seems to be irreducible over the rationals for every $n$.  For example, for $N=5$ the characteristic polynomial is
$\lambda^5 - 15\lambda^4 - 85\lambda^3 - 98\lambda^2 - 39\lambda - 5$, an irreducible quintic whose Galois group is $S_5$ (so not solvable by radicals).

The ordinary generating function for the characteristic polynomial appears to be
$$ g(z) = \dfrac{z^{2}-3 z +1+3 z^{2} \lambda -3 z \lambda +3 z^{2} \lambda^{2}-z^{3} \lambda^{3}}{z^{2}-2 z +1+4 z^{2} \lambda -4 z \lambda -2 z^{3} \lambda^{2}+6 z^{2} \lambda^{2}-4 z^{3} \lambda^{3}+z^{4} \lambda^{4}}$$

Comment: Yeah, I agree. But is there anything special about the eigenvalues? Maybe the distribution or some other relations? (except the fact that it has only one positive eigenvalue). Thanks!

Comment: @Albert Why do you think the eigenvalues obey something special here?